# Grep and replace

Tags: linux, text-processing, grep

I have a file that has a `RESOURCE` keyword. It can occur anywhere in the file, like:

```
RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@gmail.com
```

Now I want to replace `Lnreddy37@gmail.com` with `reddy17777@gmail.com`. 
I have to search for the line where I can find the `RESOURCE` keyword and then replace the word after the equal sign. The `RESOURCE` keyword has to remain unmodified.

Could some one please help me on this?

input:

```
RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@gmail.com
```

Output:

```
RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is not useful in this case as it does not allow you to modify the contents of the file.

Instead, one may use `sed` like so:

```
fromaddr='Lnreddy37@gmail.com'
toaddr='reddy17777@gmail.com'

sed '/^RESOURCE=/s/='"$fromaddr"'$/='"$toaddr"'/' file >newfile
```

Given `file` as

```
some data
RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@gmail.com
RESOURCE2=Lnreddy37@gmail.com
RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@example.com
RESOURCE=Lnreddy38@gmail.com
more data
```

this creates `newfile` as

```
some data
RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com
RESOURCE2=Lnreddy37@gmail.com
RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@example.com
RESOURCE=Lnreddy38@gmail.com
more data
```

The `sed` expression will select lines that starts with the string `RESOURCE`.  For each such line, it will replace the email address, if it's present on the line.  The pattern used for the substitution makes sure that we match the `=` and that the address ends at the end of line.

Comment: I dont want to hard code the Lnreddy37@gmail.com , it should be anything like nasir37@yahoo.com. i want to replace with any other like nasir45@gmail.com. it should be dynamic – Lakshminarayana just now   edit

Comment: @Lakshminarayana See updated answer.

Comment: I dont want to write it in a new file again .. because the file consists of other data as well. It like below.

Comment: @Lakshminarayana Then run with `sed -i` if you think it's doing the correct thing, and don't redirect to a new file. I'm generally avoiding using `sed -i` as it's non-portable and since if you make a typo, it may destroy your original data.

Comment: I understand that. how can i search for the line which is having RESOURCE word. I have to search it in a file which is having other data and have to replace it. Moreover i have to pass the file name as a parameter

Comment: @Lakshminarayana That is exactly what I have shown in my answer. You just have to put the file name in a shell variable.

Comment: @Lakshminarayana I strongly suggest that you write your requirements in the actual question. That would save both you and us time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` command is better.

```
sed -i 's/RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@gmail.com/RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com/' yourfile
```

The above works in my test but if you want to test it for yourself then you can try this one first:

```
sed 's/RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@gmail.com/RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com/' yourfile
```

That will write the changes to standard output without affecting the file.

Either way, it gives your desired change of:

```
RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com
```

If the value of `RESOURCE` is different in the file and you want to change it something different then:

```
grep RESOURCE= yourfile
```

That will return the line where it is and show the value.

You can then use

```
sed 's/RESOURCE=existingemail@gmail.com/RESOURCE=emailyouwant@gmail.com/' yourfile
```

For future reference, it's important to make all of this clear in your original question so that you can get the help that you need without all of this rigamarole.

Comment: I dont want to hard code the Lnreddy37@gmail.com , it should be anything like nasir37@yahoo.com. i want to replace with any other like nasir45@gmail.com. it should be dynamic

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In your question, it shows that you want the output to be `RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com` which both of the answers achieve. What do you mean by: "I dont want to hard code the Lnreddy37@gmail.com"? and "it should be dynamic"?

Comment: @Lakshminarayana If you want it to actually make the changes to the file then use `sed i` like I gave in my first command. Test it first with the `sed` by itself in my second command to make sure that it's doing what you want and then use the `sed -i` in my first command once you're sure that it works.

Comment: i mean i dont want to hard code them. sed 's/RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@gmail.com/RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com/' yourfile. i want to pass it like parameters both input and output. and also i want to search for that line where i have RESOURCE and have to replace it

Comment: @Lakshminarayana Then either use Kusalananda's answer and pass the email addresses to a variable or `grep RESOURCE= file`, get the email address that appears, and then use `sed -i` and replace `Lnreddy37@gmail.com` and `reddy17777@gmail.com` with whatever is there and whatever you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be saying
that you want to replace the string that appears after the `=`,
*no matter what it is* —
***for example***, in the sample data,
you want to replace `Lnreddy37@gmail.com`. 
But you’re saying that, no matter what the string after the `=` is,
you want to replace it with `reddy17777@gmail.com` —
apparently you want that hardcoded.

There are a few variations on how to do this. 
The simplest is

```
sed 's/RESOURCE=.*/RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com/'
```

which (like all the below commands)
uses the fact that `.*` means “match whatever is there”. 
If you don’t want to type `RESOURCE=` twice, you can shorten the above to

```
sed 's/\(RESOURCE=\).*/\1reddy17777@gmail.com/'
```

where `\(`…`\)` marks a part of the search string as a group
(you can have up to nine groups) and `\1` means replace with the first group.

The above commands will find and replace `RESOURCE=`
wherever it appears on the line. 
So, for example, the input

```
# Lakshminarayana wants to change all occurrences of "RESOURCE=".
RESOURCE=john@yahoo.com
COORDINATOR=paul@hotmail.com
MUSIC_RESOURCE=nasir37@yahoo.com
FOX RESOURCE=The quick brown fox
# Comment: Originally line 2 said RESOURCE=ringo@liverpool.co.uk
```

would be changed to

```
# Lakshminarayana wants to change all occurrences of "RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com
RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com
COORDINATOR=paul@hotmail.com
MUSIC_RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com
FOX RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com
# Comment: Originally line 2 said RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com
```

If you want to match only when `RESOURCE=` appears at the beginning of a line,
use **`^`**:

```
sed 's/^RESOURCE=.*/RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com/'
```

or

```
sed 's/^\(RESOURCE=\).*/\1reddy17777@gmail.com/'
```

If you want to replace only the resource value,
and not the entire rest of the line — e.g.,

```
RESOURCE=Lnreddy37@gmail.com    TALENT=george@hotmail.com
```

to

```
RESOURCE=reddy17777@gmail.com   TALENT=george@hotmail.com
```

that can be done, too. 
Edit your question to say exactly what you want,
with full, clear explanations *and* examples.

---

OK, pick one of the above **`s`** commands. 
Now, if you want to edit your file in place (as you have indicated), do

```
sed  -i  { s command }  { yourfile }
```

If you want to produce a new file, do

```
sed  { s command }  { oldfile }  >  { newfile }
```

Don’t actually type the *`{`* and *`}`*; they are there just for demarcation.